# Check for Out of Index exception for a List in C#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

How to check for out of index exception for a list. I have tried below but still it is throwing out of index exception.

`LstOfItems.Where(p => p.LstOfSubItems[i] != null)`

Comment: Where is `i` coming from?

Comment: i don't see how `.[]` is valid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LstOfItems.Where(p => p.LstOfSubItems.Count > i)
```

Simply doing `p.LstOfSubItems.[i]` will throw exception if `i` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what you are trying for, but I think you want something like this:

```
LstOfItems.Where(p => p.LstOfSubItems.All(ls=> ls != null))
```